# About FileSystem class in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

As mentioned here:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html

> "All user code that may potentially use the Hadoop Distributed File
>   System should be written to use a FileSystem object."

Does it mean: if we used the `java.io.File` class then we are not using the HDFS of Hadoop and instead we are using the hosting file system like NTFS on Windows to access the file.

Please Notice: I am not talking about Java concepts or perspective(i.e. difference between File and FileSystem classes) I am talking about the effect of using the java.io.File on HDFS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: No dear, it is completely different from what you suggested to me. I am taking here about Hadoop concepts&packages not about software engineering.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is what your quoted line means. Regardless of your filesystem implementation (Local, HDFS, S3), always use the interface/abstract class.

Comment: Dear, see the answer below @user7005835

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is: Yes

If you are using Java.io.File then you are not using HDFS file system. Java.io.File will be a filesystem like windows or linux etc.

To create a file in HDFS you need to use FileSystem object and using FileSystem object you can create a file in HDFS.

Hope this helps!